# What is it called when eeny meeny miney moe is done using a held staff?

Tags: terminology

There is a game with a staff in which each puts hand over hand in turn on the staff until the top is reached, the player with the last hand winning. Thus, it is a kind of eeny meeny miney moe. What is this game or procedure called? I am pretty sure there is an archaic term for this that dates back at least to Elizabethan times; I just can't remember what it is.

Comment: We used to do this with a baseball bat to decide the "first ups-last licks". Don´t know what it is called though, and it is possible that kids still do it in the states.

Comment: I thought an obvious choice might be *to play "fists"*, but apparently that usually refers to [Morra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morra_(game)), which looks more like a simplified version of Rock-Paper-Scissors.

Comment: According to this: http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/5/messages/290.html there may be _an English game of chance that has been traced back to the 15th century_ similar to the baseball bat method of choosing who goes first.  I couldn't, however, find what that game might have been called (and can't afford the book from which that excerpt was taken.)

Comment: these are called ***counting out rhymes***

Comment: Oh. You’re not asking about the rhymes part. You want to know what it’s called when done with a stick.  fYI I don’t think it’s obsolete people still do it with a baseball bat

Comment: This book https://books.google.com/books?id=un03ZxWU5coC&pg=PR24&lpg=PR24&dq=baseball+bat+fists+choose&source=bl&ots=Bt5oq6T8Rc&sig=TPhWpw9xM9p8lswSKchK_g_YcMo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUydmS3dbTAhVM1WMKHQQADCQQ6AEIQzAS. Calls it ***stacking hands***

Comment: It is also called "hand-over-hand."

Comment: "Drawing straws" is the only game of such type that I know of that has a well-known name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe it has a standard name; like many playground rituals, its precise name (and whether it even has a name) seems to depend on the particular locale where it is played. I've found it called ["knobbing up"](https://www.reddit.com/r/baseball/comments/1kfr0h/sandlot_baseball_question_when_deciding_which/cboierl/?st=j2ayob3y&sh=5b800902) and ["knobbies" and "bottle caps"](https://plus.google.com/+MikeElgan/posts/iFWQoSHzA62) and in comments both "stacking hands" (found by Jim in a book) and "hand-over-hand" (contributed by Yorik) have been suggested.

One possible alternative is ***getting the upper hand***, or just *Upper Hand*. There is a theory, widely repeated on the internet and beyond, that this common idiom originates with the childhood game. One representative story:

> ### [Get the upper hand](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/get-the-upper-hand.html)
>
> **Meaning**  Take a dominant position.
>   **Origin**  Various suggestions have been made as to the origin of 'get the upper hand' (or 'take the upper hand'). Prominent amongst those is that the phrase originated in American playgrounds, in the way that children select sides for impromptu baseball games. The method is for one team captain to grab the bat at the bottom, then the other captain takes hold above the first's hand and they progress hand over hand along the bat until the top is reached - the one left holding the bat having the 'upper hand' and getting first choice of player for their team.
>
> ("The meaning and origin of the expression: Get the upper hand", *The Phrase Finder*, Phrases.org.uk)

I very much doubt that this origin is correct, given that the phrase itself goes back to the fifteenth century:

> It is no nede that I telle you of one of the moost noble pryncys of good remembraūce Marcus Attilius first a labourer of the londes / and af∣tir electe consul and connestable of the batails of rome / whiche by many a tyme ouircame and **had the vppirhande** and victorye of the men of cartage mortall ennemyes to the Romaynes. ([English translation of Cicero, 1481](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A69111.0001.001/1:3?rgn=div1;view=fulltext))

This predates American baseball by a few centuries, though some ball-and-stick games predated the quote above (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseball#History)). It is thus possible that the phrase emerged from this method of decision-making, either in a game that used something like a bat or with any other stick- or staff-like thing, but the game-in-question wouldn't have been American sandlot baseball. In fact, at least one source claims that

> **Upper hand** is a saying that began with a simple 15th-century game. It involved a staff or stick, and two or more contestants. . . . This practice was adopted in the 19th century on American playgrounds to determine which side would bat first in impromptu baseball games. ([Andrew Thompson, *Hair of the Dog to Paint the Town Red: The Curious Origins of Everyday Sayings and Fun Phrases*, 2017](https://books.google.com/books?id=QCyFDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT36&dq=%22upper%20hand%22%20phrase%20baseball&pg=PT36#v=onepage&q=%22upper%20hand%22%20phrase%20baseball&f=false))

Unfortunately, Thompson doesn't include any more details about the game, and whether it was actually *called* something like "upper hand".

More to the point for the original question, I can't find any evidence that the phrase is actually used nowadays by children for this activity. However, the (folk?) etymology is now widespread enough<sup>1</sup>, and the phrase "fits" the activity so well, that you might well be able to use the expression for the activity and be generally understood. I was able to find at least one example of this usage in print:

> Vintage baseball players Al "Rocky" Belbol, with the Brooklyn Eckfords of New York,left, and Jamie "Mouth" Ford, of the Athletic Base Ball Club of Philadelphia, try to get the upper hand to determine bating order during the 2014 Base-Ball Exhibition & Fair at the Navy Yard in Philadelphia. ([Photo caption in AP article "Vintage baseball proves a hit with modern players", *Times Free Press*, September 13 2014](http://www.timesfreepress.com/news/local/story/2014/sep/13/vintage-baseball-proves-hit-modern-players/266995/). The photo shows two men playing the game described in the question.)

Depending on your audience and usage, you might want to include some context for clarity's sake (especially if you don't have an illustration). Something like:

> They played "Upper Hand" to decide who would sleep on the couch, using Grandfather's cane in the absence of a baseball bat.

---

<sup>1</sup> In addition to the example quoted above, see, for example, ["Upper Hand", *American Culture Explained*](https://americaexplained.wordpress.com/tag/baseball/); [Doug Lennox, *Now You Know Baseball*, 2010](https://books.google.com/books?id=54lWV2TmtcUC&lpg=PA53&dq=%22upper%20hand%22%20baseball%20captains&pg=PA53#v=onepage&q=%22upper%20hand%22%20baseball%20captains&f=false); Charles Hodgson, [*Carnal Knowledge: A Navel Gazer's Dictionary of Anatomy, Etymology, and Trivia*, 2015](https://books.google.com/books?id=g5nYBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA21&dq=%22upper%20hand%22%20phrase%20baseball&pg=PA21#v=onepage&q=%22upper%20hand%22%20phrase%20baseball&f=false); and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted the above answer, which concludes there is no specific term. I verified this by examining a number of old references to the practice. None of these works ever gave a name to the practice, so it is reasonable to conclude that there was none.

The Young Folk's Cyclopædia of Games and Sports (1890):

[image]